# How to create minimized ongoing notification like USB connection or google weather

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I'm developing a Xamarin.Android application that uses a Foreground Service to track user's location after certain time/distance.

To keep the service running I have an ongoing notification with Low priority as well as the notification channel with low priority too. I've tried all kind of combinations (low and min priorities and content texts).

NotificationChannel code:

```
private NotificationChannel CreateNotificationChannel(string channelId)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        return null;
    }
    string channelName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_channel_name);
    string channelDesc = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_channel_desc);
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
    {
        Description = channelDesc
    };
    switch(channelId)
    {
        case UPDATES_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID: 
            notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High;
            break;
        case ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID:
            notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.Low;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    var notifManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notifManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    return notificationChannel;
}
```

Notification code:

```
private Notification CreateOngoingNotification()
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    string content = "The application is fetching your location every " + MIN_TIME / (60 * 1000) + " minutes if you moved at least " + MIN_DISTANCE + " meters.";
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O) builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    else builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, m_ongoingNotificationChannel.Id);
    builder
            .SetContentTitle("Persistent notification")
            .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(content))
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetGroup("persistent")
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Private)
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Low);
    Notification notification = builder.Build();
    return notification;
}
```

Having the following image in mind, what I'm trying to acomplish is the style of the notifications from LinkedIn app, the Google Weather one (bottom), and the other one (3rd one starting from the end).

All I can get is the one with "Persistent notification" in the title.

[image: THIS]

Any kind of help will be welcome!

EDIT: made clear that I'm using Xamarin, not Java

Comment: What exactly do you want like when you long press and scroll down it, it should open?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong and you are looking for an [expandable notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded)

> A basic notification usually includes a title, a line of text, and one or more actions the user can perform in response. To provide even more information, you can also create large, expandable notifications by applying one of several notification templates.

Now if you read the documents carefully it has all the different types of expandable notifications,

The one you are looking for is either the `Add a large block of text` or the `Create an inbox-style notification`

Both codes available on the documentation are easily convertible to C# i.e. `Xamarin.Android`

In case you face issues or have queries feel free to revert

Goodluck

Comment: I will check it out tomorrow. But I am already using expandable notifications (the one with title KeepTravelling). The thing is that it doesn't get that minimized as other app's notifications. Anyway, I'll research on these expandable ones, I might be missing something.

Comment: Sure you can do that let me know if i can help you somehow or the other

Comment: I've tried both of these types and still getting the same layout. Should I need to make a custom layout instead of a notification type?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to add a custom layout here! can you add the image of what exactly are you trying to achieve in the question?

Comment: Ok maybe I didn't explain myself, the image added in the question shows both of my actual notification (KeepTravelling) and what I want to accomplish (bottom ones: Google Weather, LinkedIn and the other one which is usb connection options).